# ons-carouselで画像の拡大縮小を行いたい

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

現在Monacaでアプリを作成しています。
ons-carousel-itemに画像を指定してiPhoneの写真一覧みたいな
画像を拡大縮小できるカルーセルを作成しようと思っているのですが、
可能でしょうか？お分かりになる方ご教示ください。